# How to get drawstrings that re size dynamically with the component window?

Tags: java

-When I run this code, I get a component frame window with drawstrings. I want the drawstrings to rezie when the window resizes. It is fine when Im re sizing the window height but when I resize from left to right, the width, my drawstrings scroll as Im moving the window frame from left to right. What causes this problem? I wanted it to stay put.

```
   public void paintComponent(java.awt.Graphics g)
    {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;

    // Red rectangle
        Rectangle lossesBar = new Rectangle( 10,20, getWidth() - 20, getHeight() - 60);   
        g2.setColor(Color.RED);
        g2.fill(lossesBar);
        lossesBar.getWidth();

     // Draw the wins greetings
        g2.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g2.drawString("Wins = " + wins, getWidth() - 400, getHeight() -100);

     // Draw the losses greetings
        g2.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g2.drawString("Losses = " + losses, getWidth() - 150, getHeight() -100);

     // Draw the ties greetings
        g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g2.drawString("Ties = " + ties, getWidth() - 474, getHeight() - 10);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use custom painting for something like this.

Instead you should be using `JLabels` for the text. You can then use `Layout Managers` to layout the labels. Finally you can use `Borders` to display a rectangle around the labels.

Read the Swing Tutorial for the basics. There are sections on:

1. How to Use Labels
2. Using Layout Managers
3. How to Use Borders